# Reducing .parent and .children calls to get to desired parameter

Tags: javascript, html

I have an eCommerce page of products with some small thumbnails below. When I mouse moused over a thumbnail I want to swap the different variation image into the product image. I have this working using the code below but I assume this isn't the best way to do this? Can anyone suggest a better way for me to grab the "product-image" src= tag and update it? The number of parent / child calls I've used to set the right data seems excessive.

Thanks in advance. Tim

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.nSwatchProduct').hover(function(){
    var newSource = $(this).attr('data-variation-image');
    $(this).parent('._itmspec_listitm').parent('.nColourSwatch').parent('.categoryswatch').parent('.caption').parent('.thumbnail').children('.thumbnail-image').children('.product-image').attr('src', newSource);
  });
});
</script>
```

web page hierarchy

```
<div class="thumbnail">
<a href="https://www.website.com/productpage" class="thumbnail-image">
<img src="/assets/thumbL/imagename.jpg" itemprop="image" class="product-image" alt="" rel="itm">
</a>
<div class="caption">

<div class="nColourList categoryswatch">
    <a class="_itmspec_lnk thumbnail nColourSwatch" href="https://www.website.com/productpage" ref="1_83" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" data-original-title="Blue">
        <div class="_itmspec_listitm" ref="1_83">
            <img class="nSwatchProduct" src="/assets/thumb/variationimage.jpg" alt="Blue" data-variation-image="/assets/thumb/variationimage.jpg">
        </div>
    </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`.closest`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) to select nearest common parent and then [`.find`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) that element you need

```
$(this).closest('.thumbnail').find('.thumbnail-image .product-image')
```